# word wrapping in HTMLPanel

Tags: gwt, word-wrap

I have a HTMLPanel element created like this:

```
String message = "Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong"
HTMLPanel messageDiv = new HTMLPanel(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(message));
```

and this panel has a `max-width: 50px;` (for example). How can I make the word split into multiple lines so it doesn't overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `word-break: break-all;` or `word-break: break-word;`